# Date changes format (MM/dd/yyy to MM/dd/yyy 00:00) After converting from Datagridview to CSV file?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

Here is my table from `MS Access` viewed using datagridview:

```
LName              FName            DateCreated
Cena               John              12/25/2011
Parker             Peter             7/19/2010
Smith              Will              11/11/2009
```

I can successfully convert my data from datagridview to CSV File using this code:

```
  Public Sub ConverToCSVFile(ByVal datagridviewdata As DataGridView)
        Try

            'Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
            Dim csv As String = String.Empty

           'Adding the Rows
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In datagridviewdata.Rows
                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    'Add the Data rows.
                    csv += cell.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ";") & ","c
                Next

                'Add new line.
                csv += vbCr & vbLf
            Next

            'Exporting to Excel
            Dim folderPath As String = "C:\CSV\"
            File.WriteAllText(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport.csv", csv)
            MessageBox.Show("Report successfully generated", "CSV File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

But after conversion, the date changes it format in CSV File looking like this:

```
Cena,John,12/25/2011  12:00:00 AM
Parket,Peter,7/19/2010 12:00:00 AM
Smith,Will,11/11/2009 12:00:00 AM
```

**Result** should be like this:

```
Cena,John,12/25/2011
Parket,Peter,7/19/2010
Smith,Will,11/11/2009
```

Comment: Are you observing the CSV file in notepad or in Excel?

Comment: both notepad and excel. Still the same output which the time is included

Comment: In that case, `cell.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ";") & ","c` does not return what you expect. `ToString` must include the time by default. Easiest solution is to string replace `  12:00:00 AM`. Or use an explicit format string as an argument to ToString, just for your date column. (as it's making assumptions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @Nick.McDermaid, calling `ToString` on the cell's `Value` is going to invoke the `DateTime.ToString` method with no argument, do you will get the default output.  If you want a specific output then you are going to have to call a specific method of the `DateTime` type that gives you that output, which would be either `ToShortDateString` or `ToString` with an appropriate argument.  That could look something like this:

```
Dim cellValue = cell.Value

If TypeOf cellValue Is Date Then
    cellText = CDate(cellValue).ToShortDateString()
Else
    cellText = cellValue.ToString()
End If
```